# Reg Javascript in website is not working when opened via selenium script

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Javascipt is not working when I open site via web driver script.Here is the link of the site
http://www.formget.com/tutorial/register_demo/registration.html.The code is

```
WebDriver d=new FirefoxDriver();        
d.get("http://www.formget.com/tutorial/register_demo/registration.html");
d.findElement(By.id("register")).click();
```

when i manually clicked on the Register button after opening the site by script.No alert box is appearing but when clicked on the button via script alert box is displayed.Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you please share your selenium script which you have written?

Comment: d.get("http://www.formget.com/tutorial/register_demo/registration.html");
Just opened the site  from script.

Comment: Please share your full code by updating question. this is just line to open page which is not enough to help you. Are you able to open site? by web driver script?

Comment: The code:                                                                                        WebDriver d=new FirefoxDriver();d.get("http://www.formget.com/tutorial/register_demo/registration.html");
d.findElement(By.id("register")).click(); Afer opening the site when i manually click on the Register button the alert box is not displayed.But if click on the button from script the alert box appers.This is happening not only with this site but for other sites which have alert boxes for ex:https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/

Comment: first of all I think without http  , it does not open site when you try to open using webdriver. Do you able to open site using web driver code?

Comment: I have included http also but here it is not displayed

Comment: yeah I just got to know that. I can see your code in question. Do you getting any error?

Comment: No i am not getting any error

Comment: But, y do u want to click manually? script does it ..whats the use case?

Comment: Any way if the script clicks   or i click the button the functionality shouldn't change right?

Comment: Anyways, it did work for me both manually and through script. May be its some kind of browser compatible version problem with Selenium Server.

Comment: @nitin chawda What did u do exactly so that i can correct my mistake

Comment: @RachelD'cruz It's the same code which you posted. No changes at all. Anyways im using Selenium version of 2.36 and FF version 24.

Comment: @nitin chawda did u  manually click  on the Register button after opening it by script

Comment: @RachelD'cruz Yes, i did. It worked when i opened it manually and clicked manually and also it did work when i ran the script and clicked manually. Please check if 'javascript.enabled` is `true` or not when you launch the browser manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might occur when the default value of ff config `javascript.enabled` is `false`. Try to change the value by following steps:

```
1) in firefox browser type `about:config` in URL
2) Toggle the value of 'javascript.enabled` to 'true`
```

The default firefox profile might have changed the value to `false`. When you launch the firefox through `webdriver` it loads a new profile. In new profile the default value for this config will be `true` always. This might be one of the reasons for that.

Hope this might help you to resolve issue.

[image: Default Profile When you hit manually]

[image: Selenium Profile when you run the script]

Comment: In my browser 'javascript.enabled` is 'true`when opened manaually also.I am using Firefox 35.0 and latest version of selenium

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is caused by a bug in the combination of Firefox 35 and latest Selenium Webdriver (2.44.0) Please see: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8390